# Creating Static library with category

Tags: ios, static-libraries, objective-c-category

I am trying to create a fat static library which contains only a category extension of UIColor classes. I am able to create the static library but while using it I am getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance error` in my project.

After adding **-ObjC -all_load** flags also my app is crashing with same error.
So I am not sure whether my library is created correctly or not so can someone guide me through the procedure for creating it.

I have used following links for referance
[create Static library for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) and [create framework for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

Comment: In my experience `-ObjC` should do it. Do you link the library in approprite _Build Phase_?

Comment: I have followed exact same procedure as mentioned in above links.So i guess my build phase state is in appropriate condition.

Comment: one more thing as my whole library project is only one category and one supporting class.I want my category header to be consider as library header.So can i do that if yes how ?

Comment: Try adding a regular class into the static library and the use it (just `[MYClass class]`). Results of this experiment will tell us more.

Comment: I have tried that and with simple class its working fine,but the category is giving me this problem.

Comment: And after you use the class, does the category start to work? Accessing the class should load the library on demand.

Comment: @iMartin  as I suspected issue was while creating a library.I recreated project and then made the library now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try 
`-force_load $(SRCROOT)/path/to/lib`